# Problem with the command AT+CIPSTART for A7 GSM/GPRS/GPS MOdules

Tags: arduino, at-command, gprs

I have two boards AiThinker A7 and A9G GSM/GPRS/GPS MOdules. I am using the same SIM with both the boards to send data to TCP server. It works fine with A7 module, while gives error on A9G module.
The log is as follows:

**For AiThinker A7 Board**

```
AT
OK
AT+GPS=1
OK
AT+COPS=0
OK
AT+CGATT=1
+CTZV:21/02/11,03:10:47,+01
OK
AT+CSTT="pinternet.interkom.de","",""
OK
AT+CIICR 
OK
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","0.tcp.ngrok.io",16939
CONNECT OK
OK
AT+CIPSEND=138,"{ scooterId: 'C45ZA1', pm25: 234, pm10: 110 }"
OK
+CIPRCV:160,127.0.0.1:49915 said { scooterId: 'C45ZA1', pm25: 234, pm10: 110 }
```

**For A9G Board**

```
AT+GPS=1
OK
AT+COPS=0
OK
AT+CREG?
+CREG: 1,5
OK
AT+CGACT?
+CGACT: 0,0
OK
AT+CGACT=1
OK
AT+CGATT=1
+CGATT:1
OK
AT+CGACT?
+CGACT: 0,0
OK
AT+CSTT="pinternet.interkom.de","",""
OK
AT+CIICR
OK
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","0.tcp.ngrok.io",16939
+CME ERROR: 50
```

`+CME ERROR: 50` means EXE_FAIL. Please help me out. I could not figure it out. I tried a lot.

Here it is another set of command sent to understand what was going on.

**For A7 (Working):**

```
AT+CGACT?
+CGACT: 0,0
OK
AT+CGACT=1
OK
AT+CGACT?
+CGACT: 0,0
AT+CGDCONT?
+CGDCONT:1,,"pinternet.interkom.de",,0,0
OK
```

**For A9G (not working)**:

```
AT+CGATT=1
+CGATT:1
OK
AT+CGACT?
+CGACT: 0,0
OK
AT+CGACT=1
OK
AT+CGACT?
+CGACT: 0,0
OK
AT+CGACT=1,1
OK
AT+CGACT?
+CGACT: 1,1
OK
AT+CGDCONT?
+CGDCONT:1,,,"10.163.72.91",0,0
OK
AT+CGDCONT=1,"","pinternet.interkom.de","",0,0 
+CME ERROR: 3
```

(error 3 => OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED)

Comment: That `+CGACT: 0,0` response means there's no enabled PDP context. Perform the same query in the working scenario too, please. Additionally: what's the response to the `AT+CGDCONT?` command, in both scenarios?

Comment: @RobertoCaboni, For A7 (Working) AT+CGACT?
`
+CGACT: 0,0

OK
AT+CGACT=1

OK
AT+CGACT?

+CGACT: 0,0`

Comment: It seems that the read command of +CGACT doesn't make sense. Probably is implemented in a dummy way... What about +CGDCONT?

Comment: @RobertoCaboni, **For A7 (Working)** 
`AT+CGACT?
+CGACT: 0,0
OK
AT+CGACT=1
OK
AT+CGACT?
+CGACT: 0,0
AT+CGDCONT?
+CGDCONT:1,,"pinternet.interkom.de",,0,0
OK
`
**for A9G**,
`
AT+CGATT=1
+CGATT:1
OK
AT+CGACT?
+CGACT: 0,0
OK
AT+CGACT=1
OK
AT+CGACT?
+CGACT: 0,0
OK
AT+CGACT=1,1
OK
AT+CGACT?
+CGACT: 1, 1
OK
AT+CGDCONT?
+CGDCONT:1,,,"10.163.72.91",0,0
OK
AT+CGDCONT=1,"","pinternet.interkom.de","",0,0
+CME ERROR: 3
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","pinternet.interkom.de","",0,0
+CME ERROR: 3
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","pinternet.interkom.de"
+CME ERROR: 3
`
3 =>OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED.

Comment: Please, check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

You need to correctly set the APN name with the command

```
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","pinternet.interkom.de"
```

---

### Explanation

In order to reach the packet network, a cellular device needs to enable a PDP context, and that is done connecting to an access point, identified by a specific APN (Access Point Name).

In your latter compared test it is clear how the APN in the working module is correctly set to `"pinternet.interkom.de"`, while in the **A9G** device is seems to be set to a private IP address. Without a valid APN the device cannot reach the network.

You later tried to set it with `+CGDCONT` command, but you used a wrong syntax. Correct syntax is, as explained in [the specification](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/127000_127099/127007/12.09.00_60/ts_127007v120900p.pdf) , is

```
AT+CGDCONT=[<cid>[,<PDP_type>[,<APN>[,<PDP_addr>[,<d_comp>[,<h_comp>[,<IPv4AddrAlloc>,<request_type>[,<PCSCF_discovery>[,<IM_CN_Signalling_Flag_Ind>[,<NSLPI>[,<securePCO>]]]]]]]]]]]]
```

You don't need most of the optional parameters. You just need

```
AT+CGDCONT=<cid>,<PDP_type>,<APN>
```

so basically you missed `<PDP_type>` parameter. It can be set to the values `"IP"`, `"IPV6"`, `IPV4V6` and so on, according to the capabilities of the network you are camped in. For your needs you'll need to set it to `"IP"`.

Comment: As I mentioned my comments earlier I tried different formats of AT+CGDCONT, but it gives me Error 3.
`
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","pinternet.interkom.de"

+CME ERROR: 3
`

Comment: @sajjad, sorry but I just catched th empty pdp_type try. What do you get if you provide `AT+CGDCONT=?` ?

Comment: AT+CGDCONT=?

+CGDCONT: (1..7), (IP,IPV6,PPP),(0..3),(0..4)

OK

Comment: @sajjad according to the at guide https://docs.ai-thinker.com/_media/b_and_t/nb-iot/n92/kaifazhidaowendang/rda8908a_at_commandmanual9.0.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjM2I2R6uTuAhUL8hQKHdAlA5wQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw0QM4g3E4oNUJl1_ia-cayC the setting I suggested is perfectly legit. Some further attempts: 1) try `at+cgatt=0`, then retry to set `at+cgdcont` as suggested in my answer, and set `at+cgatt=1` again. 2) Try to delete the apn with `at+cgdcont=1`, then reboot the device and try to connect again to see if the apn is provided by the network.

Comment: @sajjad 3) don't change anything and provide `at+cgpaddr=1` before `+cgact`, 4) try setting the afore mentioned apn on another cid: `AT+CGDCONT=2,"IP","pinternet.interkom.de"`

Comment: @sajjad what is the response of `+cgpaddr?` After configuring cid 2 you got an error?

Comment: <pre> <code> 
AT+CGACT?
+CGACT: 0,0
OK
AT+CGDCONT=2,"IP","pinternet.interkom.de"
OK
AT+CGDCONT?
+CGDCONT:2,"IP","pinternet.interkom.de","0.0.0.0",0,0
OK
AT+CGATT=1
+CGATT:1
OK
AT+CGACT=1,2
OK
at+cgpaddr=2
+CGPADDR: 2,"10.148.205.129"
OK
AT+CSTT="pinternet.interkom.de","",""
OK
AT+CIICR
OK
AT+CIPSTART=2, "TCP","0.tcp.ngrok.io",12279
+CME ERROR: 50
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","0.tcp.ngrok.io",12279
+CME ERROR: 50
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","0.tcp.ngrok.io","12279"
+CME ERROR: 50
<pre> </code>

Comment: above is the complete output. sorry @Roberto Caboni for improper formatting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228657/discussion-between-sajjad-and-roberto-caboni).

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.ai-thinker.com/en/gprs/examples helped me out. The exact sequence that worked is:

```
Init...

+CIEV: "Charging",100%


+CREG: 2

^STN: 37
+CTZV:21/02/13,02:51:53,+01

+CREG: 1

A9/A9G
V02.02.20190915R
Ai_Thinker_Co._Ltd.
READY
+CIEV: "Complete the Charge",100%

AT

OK
AT+CGATT=1

+CGATT:1

OK
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","pinternet.interkom.de"

OK
AT+CGACT=1,1

OK
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","0.tcp.ngrok.io",12279
CONNECT OK

OK

+CIPRCV,39:SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u6

CLOSED

OK
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","0.tcp.ngrok.io",12973
CONNECT OK

OK
AT+CIPSEND=138,"{ scooterId: 'C45ZA1', pm25: 234, pm10: 110 }"

OK
```

Omitting the following commands while sending data to TCP, works. The exclude commands from the sequence are:

```
AT+CSTT="pinternet.interkom.de","",""
OK
AT+CIICR
OK
```